# zendframework 2 inputfilter customize default error message

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to customize the default error message "`Value is required and can't be empty`"
in zf2

I am using following code to add customise default error message in validators of inputfilter

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'username',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 4,
                            'max' => 20,
                            'messages' => array(
                                'isEmpty' => 'Please enter User Name between 4 to 20 character!' 
                            ),                            
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));
```

But I am getting following error.

```
Zend\Validator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException

File:
    /home/website/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Validator/AbstractValidator.php:220

Message:
    No message template exists for key 'isEmpty'
```

What I am doing wrong?

[reference](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/zend-framework-2-extending-zendform-to-add-select-multicheckbox-emaildate-textarea-and-radio-element/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'username',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                      'name' =>'NotEmpty', 
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Please enter User Name!' 
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 4,
                            'max' => 20,
                            'messages' => array(
                                'stringLengthTooShort' => 'Please enter User Name between 4 to 20 character!', 
                                'stringLengthTooLong' => 'Please enter User Name between 4 to 20 character!' 
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));
```

[reference](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/zf2-custom-messages-in-input-filter-td4655498.html)

[Other validator set](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html)

Comment: Hey, where are tje possible keys ("stringLengthTooShort", \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY, "stringLengthTooLong") documented?

Answer (score 3):

You also can set the error message of inputFilter so:

```
    $form = new ParticipantForm();  
    $mailInput = new Input('mail');
    $mailInput->setRequired(true);
    $mailInput->setErrorMessage("Empty input");
```

Answer (score 1):

The StringLength validator does not check for the input to be empty or not. It checks against lengths. Following message templates exist for StringLength validator:

```
const INVALID   = 'stringLengthInvalid';
const TOO_SHORT = 'stringLengthTooShort';
const TOO_LONG  = 'stringLengthTooLong';

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $messageTemplates = array(
    self::INVALID   => "Invalid type given. String expected",
    self::TOO_SHORT => "The input is less than %min% characters long",
    self::TOO_LONG  => "The input is more than %max% characters long",
);
```

See the example of @Developer for a direct approach. Though i suggest going with the CamelCased naming of the Validators, so `'name' => 'NotEmpty'` instead of `'name' => 'not_empty'`

You can check which messageTemplates exist if you see the code for each of the validator classes. You will find them under `./vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Validator/*`