# How do I return a custom 'isEmpty' error message from Zend\Validator\Identical in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-validate, zend-inputfilter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [zendframework 2 inputfilter customize default error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724653/zendframework-2-inputfilter-customize-default-error-message)

I'm trying to use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter to validate the input from a registration form. I have the code below that:

1. Validates the email address in the 'email' field; then
2. Checks the value in 'email_confirm' matches the one in 'email'.

This works in in all instances other than when the user leaves both fields blank. In that instance the validator for 'email_confirm' returns the error `Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty )`.

**How do I customise this error message?** I cannot set it using:

```
'messages' => array(
    'isEmpty' => 'Message Here' 
),
```

because that throws an exception saying (quite rightly) that Zend\Validator\Identical does not have a message template for 'isEmpty'. And it's not picking up the messages I've previously set for the 'email' field, otherwise it would be returning `Array ( [isEmpty] => Please enter your email address )`.

```
$this->add($inputFactory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'email',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array(
          'name' =>'NotEmpty', 
            'options' => array(
                'messages' => array(
                    'isEmpty' => 'Please enter your email address' 
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'StringLength',
            'options' => array(
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'max' => 200,
                'messages' => array(
                    'stringLengthTooLong' => "Email addresses cannot be more than 200 characters"
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
          'name' =>'EmailAddress', 
            'options' => array(
                'useMxCheck'    => true,
            ),
        ),                
    ),
))); 

$this->add($inputFactory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'email_confirm',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Identical',                        
            'options' => array(
                'token' => 'email',
                'messages' => array(
                     'notSame' => "Your email addresses do not match, please try again",
                ),
            ),
        ),               
    ),
)));
```

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY` constant this way:

```
array(
    'name' =>'NotEmpty', 
        'options' => array(
            'messages' => array(
                \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Please enter your email address' 
        ),
    ),
),
```

You can check out the [API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Validator.NotEmpty.html) for further info.

**EDIT**

Diving into Zend\Validator\NotEmpty source code I see that `IS_EMPTY` constant has `'isEmpty'` value, so it won't fix your problem. Anyway, you *should* use these constants instead of direct values in order to avoid possible updating issues.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY simply returns the constant 'isEmpty', thus it's the exact same issue as if I was calling `'messages' => array('isEmpty' => 'Message Here')`.

Comment: @Neil you are right, see my edit on that. I'm trying to find another way to solve your problem. Do the other validators show their custom messages properly?

Comment: Yes, all the other validators' custom messages work fine.

Comment: What's the exact message currently returned by `NotEmpty` when `isEmpty` email address? `"Value is required and can't be empty"`?

Comment: My _NotEmpty_ validator on the 'email' field returns `Array ( [isEmpty] => Please enter your email address )`, as per my custom message. My _Identical_ validator returns `Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty )`.