# How to customize validation message in the form in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have just started zend framework 2. I just want to know how to customize message in form for elements having require ON(true). Right now its showing **"Please fill out this field"** (If the particular textbox is empty and I click the submit button).

I just want to change this message. Initially I thought this message is coming from library

but I was wrong. Can this possible?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12725061/1053820

Comment: possible duplicate of [zendframework 2 inputfilter customize default error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724653/zendframework-2-inputfilter-customize-default-error-message)

Answer (score 7):

Please provide the method how you are creating your form. Ultimately you should simply overwrite the messages of the Validators. Each validator has the option to overwrite messages. The basic syntax is as follows:

```
// This assumes to be INSIDE a Validator
'options' => array(
    'messages' => array(
         \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => "Dude, it's empty. It shouldn't be!"
     )
)
```

The example overwrites the NotEmpty validator message if no input is given. Furthermore you should know, that if you use the HTML5 Attribute `required` then some browsers will add a pre-submit-validation to your form and the error-message displayed by the browser cannot be changed.

Comment: Hi Sam.I am using form approach(zend form) to create the html element.

Yes I was using require attribute. Still Im not getting overwrite the message.....

Comment: As i have said, be sure to set the option onto the validator. Please provide the code for how you attach the validator and I'll make it work ;) Alternatively, see the duplicate links provided by other commenters ;)

Comment: Thanks Sam. This is how the code is---
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'UserName',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => '',
                //'required' => true,
                'message' =>'Invalid',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Username',
                    'messages' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => "Dude, it's empty. It shouldn't be!",
                    )
)
));

Comment: @sam, could you please tell how to handle the custom validation message, if you're using validation message translation?

Answer (score -3):

$username = $this->createElement('text', 'username');

```
    $username->addErrorMessage('The username is required!');
```

Comment: Validation messages are a concern of the Validator, not of the Form-Element. While the Form\Element needs to know about the messages, it should never deal with creating / modifying them.