# zend 2.0 custom error message?

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

Hi i want to add custom messages to error messages. Here is my code . it is not at all working could you please how to check this code once.

```
$this->add(array(
                'name' => 'toname',
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'id' => 'toname',
                        'class' =>'toname',
                        'required' =>true,
                        'validators' => array(
                                array(
                                        'name' =>'NotEmpty',
                                        'options' => array(
                                                'messages' => array(
                                                        \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Please enter User Name!'
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                ),
                                array(
                                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                                        'options' => array(
                                                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                                'min' => 4,
                                                'max' => 20,
                                                'messages' => array(
                                                        'stringLengthTooShort' => 'Please enter User Name between 4 to 20 character!',
                                                        'stringLengthTooLong' => 'Please enter User Name between 4 to 20 character!'
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),

        ));
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724653/zendframework-2-inputfilter-customize-default-error-message

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but by that reference only i did above code... but this is not working ..the first thing notempty also not working ????????? Hmmm